# nginx container not running

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to run the command below to create an nginx container...

as you can see I am following a tutorial, the thing is I tried many commands but always get the same results... so this is my latest attempt:

`docker run --name nginx -d -p 80:80 --network some-network --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)/nginx/target",target=/usr/share/nginx/html --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)/nginx",target=/etc/nginx/conf.d,readonly nginx:latest`

I tried this with `-v` as well... I'm trying to replace the default.conf config file on the nginx countainer...

in this case I am trying to replace the contents of `/etc/nginx/conf.d` but I tried to mount the file it self so same command but with
`... --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)/nginx/default.conf",target=/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf...`

on one of my sources of inspiration I have a -v where the name of the file being placed on the content is default.conf:ro, this is from a docker-compose and I cant use one atm, not sure if the :ro is doing something... because when I use it on docker run the default file keeps being the default.conf and the :ro is next to it but not used...

can someone help me understand what I am missing on this?

Answer (score 0):

did you check https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx before? You don't need to use the nice cool features of `--mount` if you don't know what they does or how it works. Keep it simple and default. Maybe it would good to know on which OS you work. Apples MacOS works with docker a bit different and makes often problems.

You should use `-v $(pwd)/nginx/target:/usr/share/nginx/html -v $(pwd)/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro`

Comment: I only went with mount because apparently -v will be deprecated eventually... I'm on Fedora 32, with the cgroups issue fixed... but still forbidden to use docker-compose... 

why doI need to use the `:ro` ?

Comment: `:ro` is read-only - you never want to change configurations from in container to your host. Therefore, you usually use the `:ro` at the end for such configurations.

Oh Fedora, okay, I'm afraid I'm not really up to date on this.

Comment: But even when I look at the Mount argument, I don't see a problem with it. Perhaps it is indeed due to Fedora that there are problems there that have not yet been solved.

Comment: I been doing more tests... `--mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)/nginx/default.conf",target=/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` this is the part that makes the container not run... if I have this it is created but does not run... if I remove it it does run... but then I cant configure it...

Comment: I know of problems that have to do with the bind, also that it sometimes has to do with relative and absolute paths. I generally only use directories because it makes things easier and I have little or no problems with them.

Comment: I think my problem is not with docker... there is a chance that my nginx config is causing the issue... cant fully understand why it works on one project with docker-compose but fails on this one with just docker...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your nginx config file is correct...

in this case that was the problem...